# Operator expected error in xpath queries in SwiProlog

Tags: xml, xpath, prolog, swi-prolog

I am attempting to use the xpath predicate to pull out a portion of a parsed XML file, but keep getting Syntax error: Operator expected on the special characters (e.g. "/" and "@") the xpath query.  WHen I surround the query with single quotes it fails.

```
?- load_xml_file( 'books.xml', DOM ).
DOM = [element(book, [genre=romance], ['\n   Gone With The Wind\n']), element(book, [genre=thriller], ['\n   The Shining\n'])].

?- load_xml_file( 'books.xml', DOM ), xpath(DOM, //book(@genre=thriller), Book).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: load_xml_file( 'books.xml', DOM ), xpath(DOM, //
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: book(@genre=thriller), Book) . 

?- load_xml_file( 'books.xml', DOM ), xpath(DOM, '//book(@genre=thriller)', Book).
false.
```

The contents of books.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book genre="romance">
   Gone With The Wind
</book>
<book genre="thriller">
   The Shining
</book>
```

Comment: Call you please post books.xml as well?

Comment: I've tried '//book(@genre=thriller)', '//book'(@genre=thriller), '//book'('@genre'=thriller) and '//book'('@genre=thriller').  None of these return false or ERROR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you miss the declaration

:- use_module(library(xpath)).

Comment: +1: This is correct; xpath.pl in the SWI-Prolog library declares `op(400, fx, //)`, amongst other XPath operators like `/` and `@`, so that writing the term `//book(...)` is actually interpreted correctly as the term `//(book(...))`, which is required for parsing. Atomic xpaths don't appear to be handled.

Comment: @sharky: I use often xpath, and that operator causes some damn small bug in syntax highlight. Probably there is some race condition in the IDE...